# What is $\omega \times v$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, centripetal-force, angular-velocity

I found that equation in my textbook. It says that $\omega \times v$ ($v$ is velocity) is centripetal acceleration. But how is the equation derived?

Comment: What effort have you made to find an answer yourself?  Such as consulting a tutorial website or video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we assume that a particle is moving in a circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin and lying in the $x$-$y$ plane.  Using cylindrical coordinates $(\rho, \phi, z)$, the angular velocity of the motion is $\boldsymbol\omega = \omega \hat{\mathbf z}$.  The velocity is tangent to the circle and given by $\mathbf v = v\hat{\boldsymbol\phi}$.  It follows that

$$
  \boldsymbol\omega \times \mathbf v = \omega v(-\hat{\boldsymbol\rho})
$$

Now recall the standard relationship $v = R\,\omega$ between angular velocity and tangential velocity for a particle moving in a circle.  Invoking theis relationship gives

$$
  \boldsymbol\omega \times \mathbf v = -R\,\omega^2\hat{\boldsymbol\rho}
$$

which is precisely the expression for centripetal acceleration.

Comment: Can you just derive it Cartesian or polar co-ordinates ? I'm not familiar with cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @Neyamul Better yet, why not learn what cylindrical coordinates are?  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html  They're just like plane polar coordinates except with the $z$-direction added.